# Artemis service log files size

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there a way to setup file size limit for artemis service in `logging.properties` file? I couldn't find anything that talked about size of the file in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/logging.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this in the `etc/logging.properties` file:

```
# Size Rotating File handler configuration
handler.ROTATING_FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.SizeRotatingFileHandler
handler.ROTATING_FILE.level=INFO
handler.ROTATING_FILE.properties=autoFlush,fileName,rotateSize,maxBackupIndex
handler.ROTATING_FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.ROTATING_FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/activemq.log
handler.ROTATING_FILE.formatter=PATTERN
handler.ROTATING_FILE.rotateSize=1024000
handler.ROTATING_FILE.maxBackupIndex=20

# Formatter pattern configuration
formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %s%E%n
```

Make sure you update the `logger.handlers` to use the new `ROTATING_FILE` handler, e.g.:

```
logger.handlers=ROTATING_FILE,CONSOLE
```